# Why is character sum of eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Working my way through a first course in Representation theory, I run into some difficulties (due to bad knowledge of linear algebra) with that said I am wondering about the following. Let $\Theta : G\rightarrow V$ be a representation of $G$ with corresponding character $\chi$. Here $V$ is a complex vector space. We know that $\Theta (g)$ has at least one eigenvalue over $\mathbb{C}$ by fundamenthal theorem of algebra. If $v$ is an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda _v$ of $\Theta (g)$ and if $m=O(g)$ we have that $v=\Theta (g)^nv=\lambda _v ^nv$ which shows that the eigenvalues of $\Theta (g)$ are n:th roots of unity, in partiqular if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\Theta (g)$ then $\lambda ^{-1}=\overline{\lambda }$. From this statement, there seams to be many conclusions made that I don't quite follow:
My professor writes; let $\lambda _i$ be the eigenvalues of $\Theta (g)$. Then $\chi (g^{-1})=\sum \lambda _i ^{-1}=\sum \overline{\lambda _i}=\overline{\chi (g)}$ and $|\chi (g)|=|\sum \lambda _i|\leq \sum |\lambda _i|=\chi (1)$.

So, my confusion is do to the equality $\chi (g)=\sum \lambda _i $, i.e it seams that we are guaranteed an eigenvalue basis for $V$ in which $\Theta (g)$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalue entrys. How can I see this? My professeor does not discuss this at all, which makes me believe I am missing something trivial. If for example, there are hiqher dimensional irreducible G-modules in the decomposition of $V$ how can we then expect an eigenvector basis for that submodule, I could work out this for $G$ abelian (there are no higher dim irred G-modules) but for G-non abelian? Please answer as detailed as possible!

Comment: (1) Eigenvalues don't necessary have enough eigenvectors, but they do have at least one eigenvector. A matrix need not be diagonal, only upper triangular (Jordan canonical form). (2) But yes, actually $\Theta(g)$ is diagonalizable since its minimum polynomial divides the polynomial $x^{|g|}-1$, a  polynomial with no repeated roots.

Comment: (3) You are right that non-abelian groups present problems. However, to define the character $\chi(g)$, we only need the abelian group $\langle g \rangle$ where the eigenvectors are plentiful. For different group elements, you get different eigenbases.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).